# ASCII text sent with pySerial becomes appended at end device

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, plc

I am trying to send two lines of ASCII text to a device, but the device reads these two lines as one line appended. Is it matter of delay or wrong end char? I cant really seem to see the problem.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-FTVFV0X7', 19200, timeout=10)
ser.write("x0")
ser.flush()
ser.write("11")
ser.flush()
```

The end device receives this as `x011` instead of `x0` and `11`.

When tested from ordinary terminal program there is no problem receiving the two lines seperately.

Comment: What else would it receive? 0x0 + 11 = 0x011.

Comment: @Ken, please do not be mistaken. I am talking about ASCII chars and not HEX.

Comment: @bernie, actually made a new line, but the problem is that the second line is received as `\n11`. The new line char will mess up everything.

Comment: @bernie, if i just use `\n` it will be appended aswell.. So i will receive `x0\n11`

Comment: @bernie, thing is that `os.linesep` worked, but the `\n` is messing it up. Could this be a sign of a missing end char?

Comment: @bernie, it actually sent two seperate strings, but the second line becomes `\n11` instead of `11`. What does linesep exactly do?

Comment: `os.linesep`: "The string used to separate (or, rather, terminate) lines on the current platform."

Comment: Hmmm, in this example ( http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#eol ) they use `\n`...

Comment: @bernie, i have tried this method aswell, still dont get the new line.. Everything is appended at end device..

Comment: What 'device' are you sending to?  Does it expect a `<CR>` to terminate a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of hardware serial devices use a carriage return to signal the end of a line or instruction.  Without knowing what device you are trying to communicate wth (or the protocol it expects), I would probably suggest trying

```
ser.write("x0\r")
ser.flush()
ser.write("11\r")
```

As indicated in the [documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#eol), pySerial does not support EOL parameters for `readline()` any longer so if the device is returning replies to you (and is doing so with `\r` terminated lines) then you should do as advised and use `io.TextIOWrapper` and appropriate timeouts to parse incoming data as well.